# Has anyone had much success recently using the Cappuccino Framework?

Tags: frameworks, cappuccino

I'm just creating my first project in Cappuccino without a lot of success. Looking for examples and documentation, there isn't a lot out there...

The differences from real Objective-C and the lack of libraries mean you cannot easily convert code directly from say a OS X desktop app. to Cappuccino.

As an experienced PHP, and RoR developer (besides the Java, VB, VC.....) I can't quite see the logic of abstracting/wrapping JavaScript in another language.

Any comments or suggestions for a more efficient framework?

Comment: did you try getting on the cappuccino irc channel?

Answer (score 3):

If you have specific questions that can't be answered in the IRC channel (it just depends who's in there) you should post the question to the mailing list and someone will help you.

As for why you would want objective-j I'll point you to this blog post which contains several reasons why objj exists. http://cappuccino.org/discuss/2008/12/08/on-leaky-abstractions-and-objective-j/

Answer (score 3):

I have converted several Objective-C classes nearly line for line into Cappuccino. Mostly it's a matter of changing NS to CP and changing pointers to non-pointers. What differences between Objective-C are you thinking about?

Indeed you could even take your existing XIB files from your Cocoa desktop app and convert them to Cappuccino using nib2cib. Here's how to work with Interface Builder using XCode 4: http://groups.google.com/group/objectivej/browse_thread/thread/786331dbcbc9c7b1.

Answer (score 0):

I also recently started a project in Cappuccino and what I could say is: definitely it worth it. I'm used with javascript as well as (but less) cocoa (which helps). In short, the javascript is very fine, probably one of my favorite language because of it's flexibility. But it does lack of structure. For example there is no class in javascript and you have to trick with object inheritances, prototyping and so on. By using the Cappuccino framework at first you have all those very convenient facilities but also you do not reinvent the wheel each time. This is cross browser standardized so that you only have to focus on your code and not on the IE whims. As it is based on cocoa, cappuccino also comes with the MCV scheme in mind which again let you structure your project in an efficient way.

Ok you probably already know all this. What I could tell now about the learning curve is that I had to find the right tools to really get in. i.e.[Installing cappuccino](http://www.cappuccino.org/starter) (`sudo Starter/bootstrap.sh`), creating a simple nib application (`capp gen -t NibApplication YourApplication`) then using [xcodecapp-cocoa](http://antoinemercadal.fr/xcodecappcocoa/) to listen, convert and open the project into Xcode what probably the hardest part of this learning curve to me…

Now if you are still not satisfied with cappuccino, I can only suggest to look at another framework like http://javascriptmvc.com/ , www.grooveshark.com used it to do their amazing webapp-site but I personally would never go back to html for building a web application. (conversely I would not use cappuccino for a webpage neither, "The cobbler should stick to his last")

Answer (score 0):

I began writing cappuccino a couple of months ago and had a lot of difficulty when it came to setting up the proper development environment. I also had numerous problems writing working client server code that worked well.

I eventually broke through and started doing better with Cappuccino and then I found these video tutorials that would have helped so much earlier on. They did cost me $30 but I really wished I had watched these at the start because they help you get set up properly as a developer and get you started on the right learning curve.

I actually discovered these videos when using Cappuccinos IRC which has helped me a couple of times when I couldn't find an answer.

Info on the videos here: http://cappuccino.org/discuss/2011/10/19/cappuccino-training-course-ideveloper-tv/